# CDK hash for asset zip keeps changing when code doesn't change

Tags: java, gradle, zip, aws-cdk, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucket Pipeline that runs `gradle build` > `cdk deploy`.

I am using gradle to build and zip a directory of Java code, then using this zip to deploy a lambda function with cdk Java.

```
Function.Builder.create(this, "mylambda")
                .code(Code.fromAsset("somepath/mylambda/build/distributions/mylambda.zip"))
```

At the end of running the Bitbucket Pipeline, it outputs the asset at `cdk.out/asset.<hash>.zip` where `<hash>` keeps changing, even when the code does not. So this is clogging up my S3 with a bunch of asset zips that have the same code.

I had to use a Bitbucket Pipeline changeset to work around this, but I don't think this should be necessary and doesn't seem like the proper solution. I feel like the hash shouldn't be changing.

```
    - step:
        name: "deploy"
        condition:
          changesets:
            includePaths:
              - somepath/mylambda/**
```

I am not sure where the issue is, whether it's in gradle or cdk or the Bitbucket Pipeline, that is causing redundant asset zips. Any ideas why the hash keeps changing?

UPDATE: It seems like it works as expected when cdk commands are ran locally on my laptop: same code => same asset hash, but when running the Bitbucket Pipeline to build with cdk on the exact same commit, it generates different asset hashes and wants to redeploy the same code every time.

UPDATE 2: Nevermind, the local run was using the gradle cache, so `./gradlew clean build` still changes the asset hash when I would not like it to.

CDK version:

```
2.87.0 (build 9fca790)
```

Local version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-10-14 16:13:12 UTC
Revision:     312ba9e0f4f8a02d01854d1ed743b79ed996dfd3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.19 (Amazon.com Inc. 11.0.19+7-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.1 aarch64
```

Bitbucket Pipeline version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-10-14 16:13:12 UTC
Revision:     312ba9e0f4f8a02d01854d1ed743b79ed996dfd3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.16 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.16+8)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-1040-aws amd64
```

Comment: The zip format includes timestamps for "created" and "modified". (These fields were retired in newer versions of pkzip but still exist on the file entries.) These fields may cause the archive to have a different hash from one that was constructed at a different time.